# qt show an image for 1/4 of a second

Tags: c++, qt

Hey I have tried several times to complete this using usleep or the qt sleep when showing an image but sometimes (almost every time) it shows up white instead of the image
  basically i want it to accept any input to say im ready cin will do, then show a random image numbered 1-28 in a random time ranging 1.5-3secs then show it for 250milisecs then hide and wait 2secs the show the picture for 3secs then repeat. I am on debian, g++; 
thanks in advance.

```
int getRandInt(int x){
    return rand() % x;
}



class I : public QThread
{
public:
        static void sleep(unsigned long secs) {
                QThread::msleep(secs);
        }
};



QApplication app(argc, argv);

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "images/" << getRandInt(28) << ".jpg";
std::cout << oss.str();

QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(oss.str());

QPixmap pixmap(qstr);
QPixmap pixmap2(qstr);

QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
QSplashScreen splash2(pixmap2);

QMainWindow mainWin;

while(1==1){
    splash.show();
    splash.showMessage(QObject::tr("test"),
    Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop, Qt::black);
    app.processEvents();
    I::sleep(250);
    splash.finish(0);
    splash.raise();   
    I::sleep(2*1000);
    splash2.show();
    splash2.showMessage(QObject::tr("test"),Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop, Qt::black);
    app.processEvents(); I::sleep(5000);splash2.finish(&mainWin);splash2.raise(); 
}
```

Comment: during sleep no processEvents will be called. Create a loop having a clock_t compare for looping the desired time and calling processEvents would help. A sleep freezes the complete application, therefore NOTHING will be done during sleep.

Comment: QSplashScreen is for, well, splash screens. If you want to show images, use a `QLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

With an understanding that "show a random image numbered 1-28 in a random time ranging 1.5-3secs then show it for 250milisecs" means "show a random image numbered 1-28 in a random time between 1.75s and 3.25s", the below does it.

The code requires Qt 5.x and a C++11 compiler. I tried to highlight proper use of C++11 [pseudorandom number facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). I don't know the end-use of your code, but if you substituted `std::mt19937_64` for `random_engine`, it'd be good enough for running psychological research as far as randomness goes.

The images shown are randomly drawn from a set of 28 images. Each of the source images are also randomly generated.

Notice the conspicuous absence of any form of sleep or busy-looping, and zealous use of lambdas. This code wouldn't be any shorter were it written in Python. That's what C++11 buys you: conciseness, among other things :)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <random>

typedef std::default_random_engine random_engine;

QImage randomImage(int size, random_engine & rng) {
   QImage img(size, size, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
   img.fill(Qt::white);
   QPainter p(&img);
   p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
   int N = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(25, 200)(rng);
   std::uniform_real_distribution<> dP(0, size);
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dC(0, 255);
   QPointF pt1(dP(rng), dP(rng));
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      QColor c(dC(rng), dC(rng), dC(rng));
      p.setPen(QPen(c, 3));
      QPointF pt2(dP(rng), dP(rng));
      p.drawLine(pt1, pt2);
      pt1 = pt2;
   }
   return img;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   std::random_device rd;
   random_engine gen(rd());

   int imageSize = 300;
   QList<QImage> images;
   for (int n = 0; n < 28; ++n) images << randomImage(imageSize, gen);
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dImage(0, images.size()-1);

   QStackedWidget display;
   QPushButton ready("I'm Ready!");
   QLabel label, labelHidden;
   display.addWidget(&ready);
   display.addWidget(&label);
   display.addWidget(&labelHidden);

   QTimer splashTimer;
   QStateMachine machine;
   QState s1(&machine), s2(&machine), s3(&machine), s4(&machine);
   splashTimer.setSingleShot(true);

   QObject::connect(&s1, &QState::entered, [&]{
      display.setCurrentWidget(&ready);
      ready.setDefault(true);
      ready.setFocus();
   });
   s1.addTransition(&ready, "clicked()", &s2);

   QObject::connect(&s2, &QState::entered, [&]{
      label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(images.at(dImage(gen))));
      display.setCurrentWidget(&label);
      splashTimer.start(250 + std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1500, 3000)(gen));
   });
   s2.addTransition(&splashTimer, "timeout()", &s3);

   QObject::connect(&s3, &QState::entered, [&]{
      display.setCurrentWidget(&labelHidden);
      splashTimer.start(2000);
   });
   s3.addTransition(&splashTimer, "timeout()", &s4);

   QObject::connect(&s4, &QState::entered, [&]{
      display.setCurrentWidget(&label);
      splashTimer.start(3000);
   });
   s4.addTransition(&splashTimer, "timeout()", &s1);

   machine.setInitialState(&s1);
   machine.start();
   display.show();

   return a.exec();
}
```